# find department with at least 2 employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make `sql` question which will show all departments with at least 2 people in it.

```
SELECT department.name
FROM department
INNER JOIN employee
ON department.id = employee.department_id
GROUP BY employee.id
HAVING COUNT(employee.id) >= 2;
```

It's not showing me anything with this query

Comment: You should group by the department's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you using `GROUP BY` on wrong column.
If you want to count employee in each department, then you need to `GROUP BY department.id`.

```
SELECT department.id, department.name, COUNT(employee.id) AS total_employee
FROM department
INNER JOIN employee
ON department.id = employee.department_id
GROUP BY department.id, department.name
HAVING COUNT(employee.id) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM department d
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee e
    WHERE d.id = e.department_id) >= 2
```

In this way if you want to change your limit (instead of 2, another value) your query will work.

If you use `INNER JOIN` if you want, in the future all departments with no employees you can't use it.